# NullPointerException when i want to use the default e4 eclispe logging

Tags: logging, rcp, e4

I get a NPE when I try to use the default Eclipse logging in a e4 application.

```java
import org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log.Logger;

public abstract class AbstractdUIPlugin extends AbstractUIPlugin {

@Inject
Logger logger;

public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
  super.start(context);
  // logger = LoggingPlugin.getLogger(this);
  logger.info("Plugin[" + getPluginId() + "] started");
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugin activators are not injected so you can't use `@Inject` in them.

Note that `AbstractUIPlugin` is a 3.x compatibility mode class, not pure e4.

You can get the 3.x `ILog` logging interface in an `AbstractUIPlugin` activator by calling the `getLog()` method.